# xevent trace doesn't return anything in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server-2019, extended-events

I'm trying to watch trace events on SQL Server 2019 and created an Extended Events session like this:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [test] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlsni.trace
WITH (MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,TRACK_CAUSALITY=OFF,STARTUP_STATE=OFF)
GO
```

However, the started session doesn't return anything when watching Live Data.
On an SQL Server 2017 the exact same thing returns data as expected.

On both SQL servers I'm using the SA account

I also tried adding a file target. But the file target also remains empty...

Is there anything in SQL Server that needs to get enabled? Any other reason for this not to work?

Answer (score 1):

Try
ADD EVENT sqlsni.sni_trace

Comment: Thank you @bytehd ! This is the modification I needed to implement Dan Guzman's solution for identifying TLS Handshake data on a SQL Server 2019 instance: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/189626/1413

Comment: Great, I just wish the SNI trace showed exactly which certificate was in use, but thats already in the registry